# Trying to convert video with FFmpeg but does not convert frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I use FFmpeg to convert videos from the command line. For some reason I have come across a series of videos where the video stream is not converted. The first frame is the same as every other.

```
Unique ID                                : 77419370860001982791600764331116915700 (0x3A3E6DAFA6F6760AE0BFC15F96AEEBF4)
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 183 MiB
Duration                                 : 18 min 30 s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 382 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.31.104
Writing library                          : Lavf58.31.104
ErrorDetectionType                       : Per level 1

Video 
ID : 1 
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : Main@L3.1 
Format settings : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames 
Format settings, CABAC : Yes 
Format settings, Reference frames : 3 frames 
Codec ID : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC 
Duration : 18 min 30 s 
Width : 1 280 pixels 
Height : 720 pixels 
Display aspect ratio : 16:9 
Frame rate mode : Constant 
Frame rate : 10.000 FPS 
Color space : YUV 
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 
Bit depth : 8 bits 
Scan type : Progressive 
Default : Yes 
Forced : No
```

The audio is fine. The transcoding goes quite fast. It clearly is not parsing the video.

```
ffmpeg -threads 2 -i %1 -f mp4 -movflags +faststart -c:v libx265 %2
```

I've never had any problems with it before as far as I know. These videos are from YouTube.

Any ideas what it could be? I've tried removing much of the settings but same issues.

Comment: Share full log of such a conversion.